# image_tag won't display image with uuid file name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Both of the files exist in the same folder (assets/images), however the t.png displays just fine while the file with the auto-generated uuid does not. What is the reason for this?

```
<%= image_tag('b9ea6033-a438-4d11-b888-de0d24f463d7.png') %>
<%= image_tag('t.png') %>
```

**UPDATE: b9ea6033-a438-4d11-b888-de0d24.png works, which points to a 30 character limit in the file name. Any name longer is rejected and does not render the image.. but why??**

Answer (score 1):

Can you try renaming the image here and on the file system....Are you gettin a red x in the browser?

LMK what happens

Comment: I'm getting a broken image link. The uuid should work since it doesn't break any naming conventions.

Comment: btw, the t.png is a rename of the uuid name.

Comment: ok I renamed the uuid to just 'b.png' and it worked. Looks like rails does not like uuid's as asset file names -- not good.